# Module facebook 5.0.1

Tags: facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a problem when built app with module fb vs >=4.0.5. And I meet a error bellow.

Need some help if anyone know this bug.

> [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
>       [ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
>        [ERROR] :    Ld build/Intermediates/Applevines.build/Debug-   iphoneos/Applevines.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Applevines normal arm64
>         [ERROR] :  (1 failure)

Comment: Did you clean (via menu or `appc ti clean`) your project first?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Xcode do you use? We recently discovered an issue where the latest version didn't work on Xcode < 7. That will be fixed in the next version being released this week. You can follow up by testing [this new version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4o4oq5q5yfbad2v/facebook-iphone-5.1.0.zip?dl=0). Thanks!

EDIT: The new version of ti.facebook is out now: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/releases/tag/ios-5.1.0